# Как правильно прописать путь к CSS для отдельного Node

Tags: java, css, javafx

Имеется следующая структура :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я хочу для созданного **MenuBar** назначить новый стиль.

Пытаюсь сделать это следующим образом :

```
//
    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    new DoBlackMenuBar(menuBar);
// здесь ошибок нет
```

### DoBlackMenuBar

```
 public class DoBlackMenuBar {
    
        public DoBlackMenuBar(MenuBar node) {
            node.getStylesheets().add(
                    getClass().getResource("menuBar.css").toString());
                   //Здесь getResourse возвращает null
        }
    
    }
```

*Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. Предполагаю что я неверно прописываю путь для getResourse(), хотя файл css лежит в метке resourses (IDE).*

**Как для любого Node назначать свои стили css, избегая тысячи строк в одном файле ?**

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122564/discussion-on-question-by-perfect-voyage----node--cs).

Comment: Дело было в адресе. нужно добавить слэш ("/menuBar.css"). Но если найдутся альтруисты, которые смогут на пальцах объяснить как работает getClass().getResource() я буду счастлив. Спасибо!

Comment: @Perfect Voyage а всё очень просто! Если указан относительный путь до ресурса, то он ищется в том же пакете, что и класс, где вызывается getClass()

Comment: @lampa Можете уточнить, вызов идёт в месте создания объекта new, или в конкретном методе/конструкторе ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сразу оговорюсь, что это применимо не ко всему, например сборщик `spring boot` или `javafx` игнорируют ресурсы в пакетах и получают их из специальной директории `resources`, которая является корневой для ресурсов.

Допустим есть ресурс

- `src/main/java/example/cat/cat.png`

И два класса

- `src/main/java/example/cat/Cat.java`
- `src/main/java/example/dog/Dog.java`

Если мы хотим получить изображение `cat.png` в классе `Cat.java` (а изображение и класс лежат в одном пакете), то следует сделать так: `getClass().getResource("cat.png")`, Что буквально означает `Cat.class.getResource("./cat.png")`, где `./` указывает на пакет `example.cat`.

Если мы хотим получить изображение `cat.png` в классе `Dog.java` (а изображение и класс уже не лежат в одном пакете), то мы должны указать либо абсолютный путь до ресурса: `getClass().getResource("/example/cat/cat.png")`, что будет означать `Dog.class.getResource("/example/cat/cat.png")`. Либо относительный путь, где пакет `dog` относится к пакету `cat`: `Dog.class.getResource("../cat/cat.png")`

Кстати да, как вы могли заметить есть конструкция `getClass().getResource(...)`, где `getClass()` получает класс текущего объекта, а есть `Cat.class.getResource()` где явно указывается класс, поэтому вызов этих двух выражений из класса `Dog`:

```
Cat.class.getResource("cat.png")
getClass().getResource("cat.png")
```

будет совершенно разные ресурсы получать. А где вызывается `getClass()` совершенно не важно, в конструкторе, методе или статичном методе. Он всегда будет возвращать тот класс, где идет его вызов:

```
class Dog {
    public Dog {
        getClass(); // => Dog.class
    }

    public void woof() {
        getClass(); // => Dog.class
    }

    public static void sleep() {
        getClass(); // => Dog.class
    }
}
```

Конкретно в вашем случае ресурсы лежат в отдельной директории `resources`, которая является корневой, т.е. все ресурсы лежат по пути `/menuBar.css`, `/menuSide.css` и так далее. Но при вызове `getClass().getResource("menuBar.css")` ресурс ищется по пути, относительно класса `DoBlackMenuBar`, т.е.: `/setSomethingtoGUI/DoBlackMenuBar/menuBar.css`

Comment: Благодарю вас за столь развернутый ответ! Ещё вопрос, насколько сильно бьют по шапке, за длинную простынь к файлу, например : "../"../"../"../cat/cat.png"   ) Ну это так, на всякий чтобы предупреждать людей перед скримером. Ведь проект может быть очень большим, а ресурсы лучше хранить в одном месте.

Comment: Да я думаю вы сами вскоре запутаетесь где лежит файл ../../../../cat/cat.png) Это не оч хорошая практика