# "Системе не удается найти указанный путь" - при работе с файлом .txt

Tags: java, spring, файлы, gradle, io

Имеется Java приложение с Spring, Hibernate, Gradle. Мне необходимо получить файл с расширением .txt и добавить его в параметр Scanner'а. Падает ошибка:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: intra-web\src\main\resources\stopwords.txt (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
```

Сам код:

```java
File file = new File("intra-web/src/main/resources/stopwords.txt");

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file, encoding);
```

Пробовал разные варианты:

```java
File file = new File("resources/stopwords.txt"); - не работает

File file = new File("stopwords.txt"); - не работает

getClass().getResourcesAsStream("stopwords.txt"); - не работает

getClass().getResourcesAsStream("resources/stopwords.txt"); - не работает

getClass().getResource("resourcesstopwords.txt") - не работает
```

Какие могут быть еще варианты? Абсолютный путь мне ни к чему...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте добавить знак слеша в самом начале пути, подробнее про ресурсы тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1264563/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba-css-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-node

Answer (score 0):

> new File()

смотрит в корень проекта, поэтому достаточно сделать так:

```
new File("src/main/resources/stopwords.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример для вот такой структуры resources:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**у вас WAR**

```
String fileName = "config/sample.txt";
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
 
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
```

**у вас JAR или WAR**

```
String fileName = "config/sample.txt";
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
 
try (InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName)) {
     String result = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
     System.out.println(result);
     } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

для **Spring Boot** можно посмотреть [здесь](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access).