# Как загрузить изображение для Rectangle?

Tags: java, изображения, javafx

```
    Image image = new Image("file:image.jpg");
    rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 200, 15);
    rect.setTranslateX(100);
    rect.setTranslateY(100);
    rect.setFill(new ImagePattern(image));
```

Я хочу в качестве фона установить изображение для Rectangle. Программа уходит в бесконечный цикл из исключений, пока я не закрою окно.

Изображение для простоты примера находится в одном пакете пакете с Main, откуда и происходит работа с Rectangle.

Вот такая бесконечная трансляция идёт в консоль, там и причина, но почему программа не видит image я не знаю.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Image must be non-null**
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.paint.ImagePattern.<init>(ImagePattern.java:44)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.createImagePatternPaint(QuantumToolkit.java:924)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getPaint(Toolkit.java:661)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.paint.ImagePattern.acc_getPlatformPaint(ImagePattern.java:292)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.paint.Paint$1.getPlatformPaint(Paint.java:48)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.shape.Shape.updatePGShape(Shape.java:963)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.shape.Shape.doUpdatePeer(Shape.java:998)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.shape.Shape.access$000(Shape.java:123)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.shape.Shape$1.doUpdatePeer(Shape.java:131)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.shape.ShapeHelper.updatePeerImpl(ShapeHelper.java:74)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.shape.RectangleHelper.updatePeerImpl(RectangleHelper.java:64)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.updatePeer(NodeHelper.java:102)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.syncPeer(Node.java:710)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.syncAll(Scene.java:2380)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.syncAll(Scene.java:2389)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2356)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2512)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:412)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:438)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:519)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:499)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:492)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:320)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Пишет же почти по русски прям ) Image must be non-null проверь дебагером загружается ли на самом деле оно, если нет то скорее всего путь неверно прописал.

Comment: Что не так может быть с путём к изображению, если оно лежит рядом с Main.java? Путь "file:image.jpg", image - это название файла. Кстати говоря в fxml, ImageView установленный через SceneBuilder работает, а в java коде нет. Пути у них отличаются, так как на путь из fxml он кидает исключение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы не против, то для вашего комментария

- Что не так может быть с путём к изображению, если оно лежит рядом с Main.java? Путь "file:image.jpg", image - это название файла. Кстати говоря в fxml, ImageView установленный через SceneBuilder работает, а в java коде нет. Пути у них отличаются, так как на путь из fxml он кидает исключение

я дам дополнительный ответ :

Если добавляете изображение через SceneBuilder, то добавлять изображение нужно ПРЯМО ИЗ ПАПКИ ВАШЕГО ПРОЕКТА В IDE.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы добавляете изображение через внутрянку, то лучше использовать class.getResourse
Я сам недавно задавал подобный вопрос, и здесь дан на него очень развернутый ответ.

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1264563/Как-правильно-прописать-путь-к-css-для-отдельного-node](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1264563/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA-css-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-node)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Image image = new Image("file:src/sample/resourses/WinImage.jpg",100,100,false,false);
    rect.setFill(new ImagePattern(image));
```

Спасибо всем за помощь, вот такой путь в моём случае работает. Параметры в Image также важны, так как без булева будет проблема с частичным исчезновением изображения. Кроме того я сделал их статичными и публичными, так как сцена может запускаться несколько раз, а это другой поток из-за этого случается баг с частичным исчезновением, поэтому изображения загружаются один раз и статичны, чтобы работали стабильно (может кому-то поможет такая концепция).